# ERROR: array value must start with "{"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, postgresql, heroku

Works in development, but not production. When I submit a habit. All the days are checked:

[image]

And when I submit in heroku logs show:

```
2015-08-15T03:37:10.067022+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by HabitsController#create as HTML
2015-08-15T03:37:10.067084+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"n+tS6pcb6WUHTCdV9BZqp/nFefhbPKAE+UTUouu2x1qK0pNulK+XNT4z8AhDuwEfZ1Z860fqnqQ/YXlARyplbQ==", "habit"=>{"committed"=>["sun", "mon", "tue", "wed", "thu", "fri", "sat", ""], "date_started(2i)"=>"8", "date_started(3i)"=>"14", "date_started(1i)"=>"2015", "trigger"=>"", "action"=>"test", "target"=>"", "reward"=>"", "tag_list"=>"", "conceal"=>"0"}, "button"=>""}
```

But then I get a validation error flash message because `:committed` days presence isn't coming out true even though they are all checked.

With further investigation I realize that I can't `mark_completed` any of the habits in production, which I think is related to the above problem:

```
2015-08-15T03:34:24.227822+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/habits/sort" host=www.personalcontrolcenter.com request_id=ef56c920-dee8-4797-967b-34354ff83fbc fwd="75.90.62.187" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=197ms status=500 bytes=274
2015-08-15T03:34:29.713874+00:00 app[web.1]: Started PUT "/mark_completed/7" for 75.90.62.187 at 2015-08-14 23:34:29 -0400
2015-08-15T03:34:29.720020+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by HabitsController#mark_completed as JS
2015-08-15T03:34:29.720027+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"id"=>"7"}
2015-08-15T03:34:29.924799+00:00 app[web.1]: PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  array value must start with "{" or dimension information
2015-08-15T03:34:29.924804+00:00 app[web.1]: : UPDATE "habits" SET "committed" = $1, "completed_at" = $2, "updated_at" = $3 WHERE "habits"."id" = $4
2015-08-15T03:34:29.924807+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 204ms
2015-08-15T03:34:29.926694+00:00 app[web.1]:
2015-08-15T03:34:29.926697+00:00 app[web.1]: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  array value must start with "{" or dimension information
2015-08-15T03:34:29.926698+00:00 app[web.1]: : UPDATE "habits" SET "committed" = $1, "completed_at" = $2, "updated_at" = $3 WHERE "habits"."id" = $4):
2015-08-15T03:34:29.926700+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/habits_controller.rb:32:in `mark_completed'
```

So I think we just need to rewrite the `habit_params` where I have `:committed => []`. I tried this without the brackets too.

**habits_controller.rb**

```
  def create
    if current_user == nil
      # If there is no user, store the goal values to the session.
      session[:habit_date_started] = [params["habit"]["date_started(3i)"], params["habit"]["date_started(2i)"], params["habit"]["date_started(1i)"]].join('/')
      session[:habit_committed] = params["habit"]["committed"].reject(&:empty?)
      session[:habit_action] = habit_params[:action]
      session[:habit_target] = habit_params[:target]
      session[:habit_reward] = habit_params[:reward]
      session[:habit_order] = habit_params[:order]
      session[:habit_missed_days] = habit_params[:missed_days]
      redirect_to valuation_signup_url
    else
      @habit = current_user.habits.build(habit_params)
      if @habit.conceal == true
        @habit.save_with_current_level
        redirect_to @habit, notice: 'Habit was secretly created. Remember, 3 strikes and your level restarts. Good luck!'
      elsif
        @habit.save_with_current_level
        track_activity @habit
        redirect_to @habit, notice: 'Habit was successfully created. Remember, 3 strikes and your level restarts. Good luck!'
      else
        flash.now[:danger] = 'Required Fields: "Committed to", "Started", and "Enter Habit"'
        render 'new'
      end
    end
  end

  def habit_params
    params.require(:habit).permit(
      :committed => [], # In development if I comment this line out it still passes
  end
end
```

**habit.rb**

```
validates :committed, presence: true
serialize :committed, Array

def save_with_current_level
    self.levels.build
    self.levels.build
    self.levels.build
    self.levels.build
    self.levels.build
    self.save
end
```

**development db**

```
t.text     "committed",    default: "---\n- sun\n- mon\n- tue\n- wed\n- thu\n- fri\n- sat\n"
```

**production db**

```
committed    | text[]                      | default '{sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat}'::text[]
```

**_form**

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes :committed, Date::ABBR_DAYNAMES, :downcase, :to_s %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostgreSQL supports [arrays columns natively](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/arrays.html), hence the `text[]` and array default in your production database:

```
committed | text[] | default '{sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat}'::text[]
                ^^           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

ActiveRecord in Rails4 supports PostgreSQL arrays natively so you don't need anything special in your model. In particular, you don't need this:

```
serialize :committed, Array
```

That will try to convert your `committed` arrays to YAML before AR tries to put them in the database. Look back at the default value for your `committed` column:

```
'{sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat}'::text[]
```

The `{...}` notation is the text representation of a PostgreSQL array. By having `serialize committed` in your model, you end up trying to put a YAML string into a PostgreSQL array column, the YAML won't look like `'{...}'` so it won't be a valid text representation of an array; hence the error complaining about a missing `{`.

The first thing you need to do to fix this problem is to remove this:

```
serialize :committed, Array
```

from your model.

If you look at the default value in your development database, you'll see the second thing you need to do:

```
"---\n- sun\n- mon\n- tue\n- wed\n- thu\n- fri\n- sat\n"
```

That's a YAML representation of an array and suggests that you're using SQLite in development. If that's the case then you should install PostgreSQL locally so that you can develop, test, and deploy on the same database.

Comment: If you're using PostgreSQL in development then that good but you've somehow ended up with different column types for `committed` in development and production. Your development database is set up to use `serialize` but your production database is set up to use an array column.

Comment: You have to decide if you want to use an array or `serialize` and then fix the other database so that both production and development match. That `NoMethodError` is probably from `committed.include? 'something'` when `committed.nil?`, you could say `committed.to_a.include?` if you want to treat `nil`s like empty arrays. Do you have existing data with NULLs in `habits.committed`?

Comment: Thank you for your well thought out answer :] So I deleted the `null` ones manually. I then switched the migration to `add_column :habits, :committed, :text, default: Date::ABBR_DAYNAMES.map(&:downcase), array: true `. Unfortunately by fixing this for production I'll have a minor problem in development, but I dont care its only production that matters. Maybe someday I'll discover the mystery of why the two are acting differently in this case :]